# How to make Panel Page variant selection rules detect URL parameter?

Tags: 7, panels

On D7 I have set up a new panel page variant and want to use it with a certain selection rule:

```
 String: URL path   Current path is "*/cars/*?buy"
```

Eg I want this panel variant to be used if the URL is `new/cars/honda?buy`.

However the above doesn't work. Adding `?buy` to the url doesnt trigger it to be used.

Would anyone know a way to set selection rule so that I can use this page variant with a give parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Selection Rule `Query string exists` does this.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to 'show' (instead of 'use') a panel page when that string exists in the url, correct? If so, would you mind elaborating how you do this I need this too.